# Email message from template not rendering content SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, content-builder

I need to create a template based email using the Marketing Cloud REST API. From the documentation it seems straightforward and everything is working - the email message is created in the correct folder and based on the correct template - however, when I go and edit the message it's completely empty. Only when I go to properties and choose "Update Email Now" (because it says the template has changed) the content from the template is rendered.

Here's my code below for the request, does anyone have any idea?

POST to /v1/content/assets

```
    {
  "name": "191125_NL_WW_LetsGo",
  "channels": {
    "email": true,
    "web": false
  },
  "category": {
    "id": 26947
  },
  "views": {
    "html": {
      "template": {
        "id": 42648,
        "assetType": {
          "name": "template",
          "id": 4
        }
      }
    },
    "subjectline": {
        "content": "%%=v(@subjectline)=%%"
    },
    "preheader": {
        "content": "%%=v(@preheader)=%%"
    }
  },
  "assetType": {
    "name": "templatebasedemail",
    "id": 207
  }
}
```

Installed package scope

```
"scope": "offline documents_and_images_read saved_content_read saved_content_write email_read email_write file_locations_read",
```

Comment: what if you do a retrieve on the asset after you click the button and then saved, are you missing some value/parameter>?

Comment: I couldn't find the missing value/param right away so I decided to just copy the entire JSON I got from the GET and use that in the request from now on. Thanks for your help!